# Как правильно обращаться к связанным таблицам?

Tags: php, yii2, crud

Сгенерироватл с помощью Gii CRUD.
Пытаюсь обратиться к свойству связанной таблице (моделе), но все они приватные
Вот так пытаюсь:

```
public function getPermissions(){
   return $this->authAssignments;
}
```

Выхлоп:

```
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(backend\modules\admin\models\authAssignment)#119 (8) {
    ["_attributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["item_name"]=>
      string(5) "Admin"
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(10)
      ["created_at"]=>
      int(1493374481)
    }
    ["_oldAttributes":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["item_name"]=>
      string(5) "Admin"
      ["user_id"]=>
      int(10)
      ["created_at"]=>
      int(1493374481)
    }
    ["_related":"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_errors":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_validators":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    NULL
    ["_scenario":"yii\base\Model":private]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

Связи:

```
public function getAuthAssignments()
{

    return $this->hasMany(authAssignment::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getItemNames()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AuthItem::className(), ['name' => 'item_name'])->viaTable('{{%auth_assignment}}', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Таблицы из миграции для rbac

Comment: public function getPermissions(){
   return $this->getAuthAssignments();
}

Comment: возвращает пустой ActiveQuery объект(ну там id только заполнено), там тоже все приватное

Comment: Это Уже другой вопрос и никак не связан с этим

Comment: Не понял, что имеете вы в виду... public function getPermissions(){
        return $this->getAuthAssignments()->select('item_name')->all();
    } так тоже все приватное

Comment: return $this->getAuthAssignments() Вернет вам асосачивний массив,где у вас скорее всего и лежит item_name.А чтобы делать так select('item_name')->all() то метод getAuthAssignments должен возвращать экземпляр объекта данной модели.

Comment: Как правильно обращаться к связанным таблицам?
вы использовали reltions но не правильно вызывали.Был дан ответ в комментариях,но вы пытаетесь задавать все новые вопросы И приводите примеры ваших реализации таким образом как будто они есть в вопросе

Comment: Аааа, дошло, вот так правильно: public function getPermissions(){ return $this->getAuthAssignments(); } Но как эти данные получить другой вопрос... Верно?

Comment: Да там в этом массиве или в объекте уже они есть.Остается просто foreach oм пробежаться по ним и получить ваs  интересующую info.

Answer (score 1):

Связанные данные будут лежать в _related. Сейчас там пусто, потому что вы не использовали жадную загрузку в модели поиска. Это чревато тем, что при генерации таблицы для каждой строки будет совершен еще один (или два) запрос к БД. Можете это увидеть в панели дебага yii. Рациональнее добавить в модели поиска

```
 $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query->with('authAssignments')
    ]);
```

Вот это вообще лишнее, т.к. полезной нагрузки не несет (за исключением другого названия)

```
public function getPermissions(){
   return $this->authAssignments;
}
```

В колонках crud добавляете

```
[
    'attribute' => 'authAssignments',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $data = '';
        foreach($model->authAssignments as $item){
          $data .= $item->something; //что-то собираем
        }
        return $data;
    },
],
```

Все, остается только добавить сортировку и фильтр, но это другая история.